# Visual C++ Critical Section and conditional variables

Tags: multithreading, visual-c++, synchronization, conditional-statements, critical-section

I have threads and each one will print a string. The code compiles but when i run it it crashes, does not even print one char. Is there any organization mistake in my code? Any idea? Thanks. I checked a few websites but no sense. I am using VS C++ 2013

```
void threadWork (void) const {
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(_sleep_time(_dre)));

        EnterCriticalSection(&criticalSection);
        if ( boolVar = false)
        {
            InitializeConditionVariable(&conditionVariable);
            InitializeCriticalSection(&criticalSection);
             boolVar = true;
        }
         inUse = true;      
        while (inUse == true)
        {
            SleepConditionVariableCS(&conditionVariable, &criticalSection, INFINITE);
            for (auto c : _printMe) {
                this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(_sleep_time(_dre)));
                cout << c;
                cout.flush();
            }
             inUse = false;
            LeaveCriticalSection(&criticalSection);
            WakeAllConditionVariable(&conditionVariable);                   
        }       
    }
};
```

Comment: `if ( boolVar = false)` This is assignment, not comparison. The condition is never true, and so `criticalSection` and `conditionVariable` are never initialized. Even apart from that, you call `EnterCriticalSection` before `InitializeCriticalSection`, which makes no sense.